# jQuery Mobile event getting transferred from one page to other

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi I have following HTML structure for my Android app with PhoneGap and JQM.

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="screen">

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="config" data-theme="a">

</div>

</body>
```

I am showing a time counter on #screen and some configuration to #config page. On touching anywhere on #screen stops counter and shows #config screen.
'#config' has a 'START' button on clicking which shows #screen again and starts counter.

To handle this I am using

```
$('#screen').bind('vmousedown', //code to show #config page);

$('#start_cycle').click(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#screen');
});
```

My problem is that if I touches on #screen somewhere, where #start_cycle will appear, then on lifting my thumb back executes $('#start_cycle').click function.

It seems that my vmouseup event is performing click event on start button, without waiting for me to click it again.

How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried this solution, but just by theory of how jQM works,

```
$('#screen').bind('vmousedown', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //code to change the page to counter page.
     return false;
})
```

The jQM says that, The v are followed by click events with a delay of 300ms on the same spot you touched. This might be the reason why your timer is getting started without you manually starting the timer. If the above didn't work, try attaching the touch events with native js methods.

Comment: This solution solved problem on virtual device, but still exists on actual device.